# Angular Js filter does not work with javascript addition operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, operator-keyword, angularjs-filter, addition

I was playing with Angular Js when I came across following issue

```
<li ng-repeat="x in capitals | orderBy:'capital'">
{{ x.country|uppercase}} : {{ x.capital|uppercase}}
</li>
```

works but

```
<li ng-repeat="x in capitals | orderBy:'capital'">
{{ x.country|uppercase+ ":" + x.capital|uppercase}} 
</li>
```

dose't work

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

That wont work as you cant use addition operator inside expression. you can write your custom filter and use that. check the below fiddle.

```
  jsfiddle.net/7nzot7jh/
```

Comment: Tried 
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in capitals | orderBy:'capital'">
                    {{ showMovie(x.country) + ":" + x.capital }}
                </li>
            </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer
This is my custom filter

```
        app.filter('alterCap',function() 
        {
            return function(x) 
            {
                var i, c, txt = "";
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    c = x[i];
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        c = c.toUpperCase();
                    }
                    txt += c;
                }
                return txt;
            };
        });
```

And in my controller I have passed

```
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$filter){
                $scope.capitals = [
                {country:'India',capital:'Delhi'},
                {country:'Sri Lanka',capital:'Colombo'},
                {country:'Afganistan',capital:'Kabul'},
                {country:'Bhutan',capital:'Norway'},
                {country:'Nepal',capital:'Thimphu'},
                {country:'Japan',capital:'Tokyo'},
                {country:'China',capital:'Beijing'},
                {country:'Russia',capital:'Moscow'},
                {country:'USA',capital:'Washington, D.C.'}
                ];
                $scope.applyAlterCap = function(movie){
                    return $filter('alterCap')(movie);
                };
            });
```

Now I can use Filter in my expression as

```
        <p>Using Custom Filter with addition operator inside expression</p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in capitals | orderBy:'capital'">
                {{ applyAlterCap(x.country) + ":" + x.capital }}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ x.country + ":" + x.capital}}
```